# How to wrap text continuous without space using CSS 2?

Tags: css, word-wrap, line-breaks, word-break

How can I wrap text which does not have any space, using CSS 2. I know we can using word-wrap or word-break which is provided by CSS 3. But here in my current scenario I need some solution to achieve this with CSS 2.

```
<div>
Thenextstepintheapplicationprocessiswritingapersonalstatementorstatementofpurpose.It'syourchancetocommunicateyourstrengthsandwhatmakesyouanidealcandidateforadmission.It'salsoachancetodemonstrateyourwritingcapabilities.Theestpersonalstatementsarejustthat
</div>
```

The situation is I am using a flying saucer for pdf generation which is only supporting CSS 2.1.

Any help would be appreciated guys

Comment: You can probably use word-spacing from regular text to stick words to each other. Wrapping should then be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in CSS 2.1

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: how did you test that it works in CSS2.1 ?